# List comprehension to generate and then sample from array that in turn depends on values in another array (index dependent)

Tags: python, list

Is there a way to perform a list comprehension where each item in the list would be generated by sampling randomly from a list itself in turn generated depending on the values of two other lists at a particular index? I realize readability would suffer, but I'm curious if I can do the following with a list comprehension:

```
def goat_door(guess, correct):
    doorlist = []
    for i in range(len(guess)):
        items = [1,2,3]
        if(guess[i] in items):
            items.remove(guess[i])
        if(correct[i] in items):
            items.remove(correct[i])
        doorlist.append(random.choice(items))
    return doorlist
```

(the famous 3 door guessing game problem).

The input list guess represents n guesses about the prize door (independent) and correct are the actual prize door for these n guesses. The function goat_door chooses a door that is neither the guess nor the price door..

I'm new to Python so trying to push the list comprehension. Can this be done with one or two list comprehensions?

Comment: What is the link with your code ? What list should be generated from what other list generated for what two other lists?

Comment: @Spirine I'm not sure I understand your question. I am trying to achieve the same thing as the for loop above but with list comprehensions. I thought perhaps the first list comprehension could generate [1,2,3] minus guess[i] minus correct[i] and then the second list comprehension could sample from each of these lists. Really the second list comprehension would be easy once I did the first. I don't know how to do the first and/or combine the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def goat_door(guess, correct):
    return [random.choice(list({1,2,3} - set(gc)))
            for gc in zip(guess, correct)]
```

or

```
def goat_door(guess, correct):
    return [random.choice(list({1,2,3} - {g,c}))
            for g,c in zip(guess, correct)]
```

Comment: Thanks Stefan. This is exactly what I was hoping for. My whole problem was forgetting about zip.

Comment: Well you could also do it without zip. It just wouldn't be nice.

Comment: Interesting. Either way it gets around my stupidity. I was lost becomes .remove() takes only 1 arg and you can't do .remove(x).remove(y) in a single operation. Silly not to think of sets.

Comment: Right, sets are kinda crucial here, I don't see a good way without them.